# Do I need to report rental income on my apartment?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property, housing, texas

Say I am renting an apartment for ~$1000 a month and I have a friend that needs a place to say. I let him stay on my couch and he pays me ~$999 a month. So I'm at a loss of $1 each month.

Do I need to report this as income?

He has stayed for more than 14 days (closer to 90), so from my understanding it's not a Tax Free rental. It's also my personal residence, and I'm operating at a net loss because my expense are higher than the revenue it's generating.

Is it considered taxable income because I would be living in the apartment regardless of him needing a place to stay? I'm a bit unclear on how it works if there is not a lease in place. He's just giving me some money each month. And I'm also technically losing money, but I don't want to owe a bunch in taxes later because of a mistake.

Comment: *And I'm also technically losing money*... are you? If he wasn't staying with you, would you still be paying rent?

Comment: Yes, but how is that different than using a car to drive for Uber and reporting the depreciation? You'd own the car anyway, right?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't be driving me to and from my dentist

Comment: Inn my opinion, you are **rent sharing**, not subleasing the apartment.

Comment: @JakeSteele I think you will find that you can't claim the whole of your car's depreciation against your Uber income, unless you are using the car *only* for dirving Uber.

Comment: "If you have a roommate within your apartment who pays a disproportionate amount of rent for the space occupied within your dwelling, you must claim the money paid to you as rental income as this falls outside of the definition of 'shared expenses.' " [source](https://www.sapling.com/8584298/do-claim-taxes-live-roommate)

Comment: @nanoman this should be an answer.

Comment: Why would a friend pay 99.9% of the rental of an apartment just to sleep on the couch? If I was paying all bar one dollar of the rent, I'd expect _you_ to sleep on the couch!

Comment: @TripeHound it's theoretical. The question was more about how it would work with taxes if I was still at a net negative.